# API difference shows other view

Tags: android

I have App but if I have emulator with Api 19+ It looks great but if Api levels is lower than 19 It set bad view.

Here is set bad dialog view (button on the bottom)
correct is Api 19:

[image]

And here you can see bad listview item style:

[image]

I don't know where is the problem so I don't know which code I can post here.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I fixed it. It was problem with layout. I removed marginBottom from Button and I add paddingBottom to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't trust 100% emulators on views.

Try to execute lint and see if you have anything wrong. Probably you are using API > 19 method when you shouldn't

You can create src/main/res/values/styles.xml and src/main/res/values-v19/styles.xml and have diferent styles for diferent versions.

Comment: Hi 

I know I can't trust emulators but it doesn't work on mobile device too

In my build.gradle file I have minSdkVersion = 16 

I didn't have my values-v19 folder so I created it 
but it still doesn't work.

Thank you for help.